# Dynamic url and Adding a the title to the end of the page url

Tags: php, url, dynamic, directory, title

I am making a page where the content is dynamic, but up til now i have only been able to get the page i want with variables such as (using stackoverflow as a example): https://stackoverflow.com/questions?q=7980734

but as seen in stackoverflow they have it as

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980734/dynbamic-url-and-adding-a-the-title-to-the-end-of-the-page-url
```

i just want to know how they make like that (using /) without creating individual pages for each question.

and also how do they add the title to the end of the url without creating a new directory.
i.e. if you type in

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980734/
```

it would still take you to the question, and then will add in the title.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time using a .htaccess file to rewrite certain URL's when they are requested will be sufficient. For example stackoverflow might use something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/([_\-\&\'\,\+A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ questions.php?q=$1
```

This would make both stackoverflow.com/questsions/1234/a-title-of-a-page and stackoverflow.com/questions.php?q=1234 the same page, so on your website you would need to use the "tidy" version of the URL (the first one)

A lot more can be read into this and you can customize you're URL's to what you require. For example, a few places to read up on it include:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

http://www.easymodrewrite.com/

Comment: okay i get the stackoverflow.com/questsions/1234 poart but how do i et the title of the page from a database and put it in the url... I am not clear how that would occur

Comment: also, when i do that... the styles no longer appear on the page... whats wrong?

Comment: Probably cause you've set a relative path to the stylesheet (and possibly links, js files, etc on the page too). If you start the link to all files with "/" then it'll go from the root of the website.

Comment: okay thanks! any idea about how to get the title from the page and put it on the url?

Answer (score 1):

This is called URL rewriting, essentially you have a handler that interprets the URL coming in.  It does not mean it is 'exact' directory structure, just programmatic path to 'something'.

Server side, it has scrips for instance `/questions/` might be the script/file/app that accepts the id `7980734` and a friendly url link of `dynamic-url-and-adding-a-the-title-to-the-end-of-the-page-url`

easy enough, you don't have to use numeric ID's to look up records in a db, just use text too, make it URL safe (php function for that).

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply... if i had http://domain.com/view.php?123456 and i wanted to have http://domain.com/view/123456/Question Name/   What would i do? I an not that good with .htaccess so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I think is to drop an .htaccess file in your root folder with a content something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^questions/(.*)$ /questions.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will internally route the request http://domain.com/questions/7980734 to http://domain.com/questions.php?id=7980734

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), or you can look into maybe an [MVC framework like Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/) which routes URLs to specific php controller files.

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable it in .htaccess of your project using enable mod_rewrite. Plus you must have a look at the apache configuration httpd.conf and check that mod_rewrite is added. So you can direct all traffic to a url parser in your project. 
Other than that, you must a have a logic of controllers in your application where you get the url string and determine the controller file for the url and the parameters.

Look here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for more information.